# Instance configuration in Object Oriented PHP

Tags: php, static-methods

I'm searching the most efficent way to apply a set of properties(configuration) to a newly created instance. My first objective is to keep the application object oriented, the second one is the ability to work with an DI container. This is a sample that I have come up so far:

```
class ViewLogin {
  public $msgLoginGranted;
  public $msgLoginFailed;

  public function __construct(){
  }

  protected function onSuccess() {
    return $this->msgLoginGranted;
  }

  protected function onFailure() {
    return $this->msgLoginFailed;
  }
}

class ControllerLogin {
  public function __construct(ModelLogin $model, ViewLogin $view) {
  }
}
```

In order to keep ViewLogin clean and separate configuration data from code what is the best thing to do:

**Create a new class ViewLogin1**

```
class ViewLogin1 extends ViewLogin {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->msgLoginGranted = 'Welcome!';
    $this->msgLoginFailed = 'Login Failed!';
  }
}
```

*CONS: static class content, no new functionalities, pollutes class space*

**Pass a configuration object to ViewLogin**

```
class ViewLogin {
  public function __construct(Config1 $config) {
    $this->msgLoginGranted = $config->msgLoginGranted;
    $this->msgLoginFailed = $config->msgLoginFailed;
  }
}
```

**Create a decorator for ViewLogin?**

**Move configuration to XML/JSON/YAML...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you need `ViewLogin1`. If you would like to prepare it in your framework and use it right away in application I'd go with `ViewLoginAbstract` in framework and `ViewLogin` in application even if no new functionality would be introduced (remember you'll may want to replace redirect with `die('What the hack are you trying to do?')` or something like that).

On the other hand, when you have multiple login forms in your application, I'd go in the way like [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/index.html) is going.

When you take a look on how they use [`*Controller` class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html#create-the-controller) they use one class for each controller and one generic [`ViewModel` class](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Model/ViewModel.php) for views.

In more detail default [`indexAction`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php#LC33):

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'content' => 'Placeholder page'
    ));
}
```

So I'd reuse `ViewLogin` and just pass configuration since no new functionality is introduced (just be sure you will not want to add logging or another feature in future).

Hover in my opinion redirecting page after login should be responsibility of controller not view (view should be responsible only for displaying html + other front end stuff) so I'm not really sure why you put `redirect` into view.

Comment: You are correct about the redirect thing... I messed up when trying to write this imaginary example. Changed to messaging.

Comment: @user1517081 in that case, you definitely use just options. :)